# Puppeteer picking up wrong element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've successfully set up the rough framework of a script for Puppeteer on a Raspberry Pi. My goal is to scrape data from my electricity account to use in a home automation system.

I have no JavaScript experience and have hobbled together portions of the script from various examples. I don't have the know-how to adapt the script for my specific needs.

The script currently -

1. Logs into the account with Username and Password,
2. Finds the text relevant to the search term,
3. Saves the text to a file,
4. Saves a screenshot of the web-page to a file,
5. Prints the text to the console,
6. Sends text via UDP to the home automation system.

Here is the script -

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async()=> {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({product: 'chrome', executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser', userDataDir: '/home/data', headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://selfserve.synergy.net.au/my-account.html');
    await page.type('#loginForm-username', 'My_Username');
    await page.type('#loginForm-password', 'My_Password');
    await page.click("button[type=submit]");

    await page.waitFor(30000);
    const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent);
        });
    await page.screenshot({path: 'Synergy_Login.png'});
    
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFileSync('/home/file.txt', price[0]);
        
    console.log(20, price[0]);
    
    client.send('Hello World!',0, 12, 7001, '10.1.1.3');
                
    await browser.close();
    
    client.close();
    
})();
```

Unfortunately, the text I see is the wrong text element in the web page. The search term picks up an earlier text element because there are many instances fitting the search term.

The web-scraping script uses the search term as follows (where ".ng-binding" appears immediately before the text I require) -

```
const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent);
        });​
```

The web-page has the following code around the field I wish to scrape -

```
</div>
    <!-- ngInclude: 'app/routes/user/account/dashboard/dashboard-usage.html' --><div ng-include="'app/routes/user/account/dashboard/dashboard-usage.html' " class="ng-scope"><div ng-controller="DashboardUsageCtrl as dashboardUsageCtrl" class="ng-scope">

    <!-- ngIf: accountCtrl.isCollective() -->

    <!-- ngIf: accountCtrl.isAmiCustomer() && !accountCtrl.isCollective() --><div class="account-history panel ami-account-summary ng-scope col-md-6" ng-if="accountCtrl .isAmiCustomer() && !accountCtrl.isCollective()" ng-class="{true:'col-md-6',false:'col-md-12'}[dashboardUsageCtrl.isResidential]">
        <div class="panel header">
            <div class="panel-header-container">
                <h2 class="pull-left panel-title">
                    Energy usage
                </h2>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Energy usage tooltip" ng-click="dashboardUsageCtrl.amiEnergyToolTip()" class="pull-right title-info-icon" data-event="site-interaction" data-location= "body" data-description="Energy usage tooltip" data-type="link">
                    <span class="sy-icon--circle_info"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel body">
            <!-- ngInclude: 'app/routes/user/account/dashboard/ami/ami-account-summary-chart.html' --><div ng-include="'app/routes/user/account/dashboard/ ami/ami-acccount-summary-chart.html'" class="ng-scope"><div class="usage-bar-chart ng-scope" ng-controller="AmiAcSummaryCtrl as amiAcSummaryCtrl">

    <!-- ngIf: amiAcSummaryCtrl.showChart && amiAcSummaryCtrl.isActiveAcWithUnbilledAmounts() --><div ng-if="amiAcSummaryCtrl.showChart && amiAcSummaryCtrl.isActiveAcWithUnbilledAmounts()" class="ng-scope" style="">
        <div class="content">
            <p class="text"><b class="ng-binding">Total unbilled tariff charge is $0.54-</b></p>
            <a title="Link to supply charges and GST" sy-doc-href="synergy.pricecharges.brochure" target="_blank" data-event="site-interaction" data-location="body" data-description= "Link to supply charges and GST" data-type="hyperlink" href="https://www.synergy.net.au/-/media/Files/PDF-Library/Standard_Electricity_Prices_Charges_brochure.pdf?desktop=true">
                Includes supply charges and GST
            </a>
            <p><b>*Prices are subject to change</b></p>
        </div>​
```

The text I wish to send to the home automation system is "Total unbilled tariff charge is $0.54-". How can the search term be constrained to better target just that text element?

The text that is sent via UDP to the home automtion system is currently "Hello World!". I want to send the variable Price[0], where Price[0] should reflect the text "Total unbilled tariff charge is $0.54-".

Comment: **This post severely lacks correct [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as specified by StackOverflow.**

Comment: **This post does not clearly ask a question, nor is the question in the title.**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can add further constraints; probably the easiest are through using CSS selectors and filtering.

### Using [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)

In your question, you're selecting using `.ng-binding` which matches all elements of class `ng-binding`. You can refine it by having a more selective selection. For instance, you could use `.content .ng-binding`, which returns only elements that have class `ng-binding` and are a descendent of an element that has `content` class.

To use this, for example, change:

`return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent);`

To:

`return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".content .ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent);`

### Using Filters

If there are still multiple selections, or if you want to go another route, you can filter the items based off of the value of the `textContent`. In this case, you can use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which returns only elements that meet a certain criteria. It could look something like this:

```
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent)
         .filter(content => content.startsWith("Total unbilled"));`
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Both of those variations worked fine (although the Filter option initially threw an SyntaxError - just needed a second close bracket after ("Total unbilled"));

Comment: Lastly, the UDP client.send function sends 'Hello World!' How do I change that to send "Total unbilled tariff charge...etc." The console currently prints "20 Total unbilled tariff charge is $0.54-". I don't need the 20 at front.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you're running `console.log(20, price[0])`. As you may suspect, to leave out the `20`, it would be `console.log(price[0])`. If you want to send that to UDP, you would replace the part that says `'Hello World!'` with `price[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Steve. Here's example code for anyone who wants a single metric from a username/password protected web-page using Puppeteer (web-page screenshot, metric saved to file, metric printed to console and sent via UDP).

```
// Synergy Unbilled Tariff Metric using Puppeteer

var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async ()=> {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({product: 'chrome', executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser', userDataDir: '/home/synergy_web_scraper/data', headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://selfserve.synergy.net.au/my-account.html');
    await page.type('#loginForm-username', 'My_Username');
    await page.type('#loginForm-password', 'My_Password');
    await page.click("button[type=submit]");

    await page.waitFor(30000);
    const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".content .ng-binding")).map(x => x.textContent);
        });
    await page.screenshot({path: 'Synergy_Login.png'});
    
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFileSync('/home/synergy_web_scraper/file.txt', price[0]);
        
    console.log(price[0]);
    client.send(price[0], 7001, '10.1.1.3');
    await browser.close();
    client.close();
    
})();
```